# Overlapping Activities in Android

Tags: android, view, android-activity, android-layout, activitygroup

I'm trying to implement a native MapView inside a web-based application framework (quickconnect). Right now the entire framework consists of one Activity (this is unavoidable, as the framework runs the body of the app entirely in a WebView, and the framework parses javascript calls to native functionality, such as sound and native system views). What I've realized is that MapView is an odd beast in that it needs to be run inside of a MapActivity.

So this leaves me with two options, convert the single Activity that runs the framework into a MapActivity, adding methods to manipulate the MapView inside (the issue with this is that we're looking to contribute the code back to the framework project, and the system treats MapActivities differently than normal Activities, causing all non-map apps to use up more resources than necessary), or somehow overlaying the MapActivity on top of the main Activity, which is running the WebView, with the main activity communicating with the MapActivity via Intents.

I fully realize that overlaying Activities is a complete contradiction to the design of Android apps, but I am wondering if it's possible. I've looked into ActivityGroups, and I can't find any examples of a custom ActivityGroup that shows two Activities on the screen at the same time, nevermind overlapping.

tl;dr: Is implementing overlapping Activities possible in Android, and how do I do it?

Comment: Your question needs space, blank lines and maybe a question mark at the end with a clear question...

Comment: Cleared it up a bit, added a lot of explanation because I know it's completely against Android design.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear how your objective will actually work. Let's suppose you do have "overlapping Activities". Then what? What have you gained? It's not like the JavaScript code from the first activity can do anything with the second activity. You're going to have to implement 100% of your business logic for the `MapActivity` in the `MapActivity`. Since you are going to have to teach "quickconnect" how to call `startActivity()` regardless, just implement your map as a regular `MapActivity`, in Java, and be done with it.

If, OTOH, your objective is for quickconnect-supported JavaScript code to manage the `MapView`, then you have no choice but to refactor the whole of quickconnect to use composition rather than inheritance, so the quickconnect engine can be used inside an `Activity` or a `MapActivity`. That may prove necessary over the long haul anyway, since `FragmentActivity` is necessary for using fragments in the Android Compatibility Library, and one might imagine that quickconnect should provide tablet and TV support using fragments.